# How can I fill a sparse Pandas DataFrame so that each combination of identifiers has every week represented with a fill value of 0?

Tags: python, pandas

I have sparse animal disease data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['S', 'A', 'b1', 'p1', '2014-10-19', 1],
    ['S', 'A', 'b1', 'p1', '2014-10-26', 3],
    ['S', 'A', 'b1', 'p2', '2014-10-26', 4],
    ['S', 'A', 'b2', 'p3', '2014-10-19', 1],
    ['S', 'B', 'b1', 'p1', '2014-11-02', 5],
    ['S', 'B', 'b1', 'p2', '2014-10-19', 7],
    ['S', 'B', 'b1', 'p2', '2014-10-26', 1],
    ['S', 'B', 'b1', 'p2', '2014-11-02', 2],
    ['S', 'B', 'b2', 'p2', '2014-11-02', 1],
    ['S', 'B', 'b2', 'p3', '2014-10-26', 2],
    ['S', 'B', 'b2', 'p3', '2014-11-02', 3],
    ['M', 'A', 'b1', 'p1', '2014-10-19', 6],
    ['M', 'A', 'b1', 'p1', '2014-11-02', 2],
    ['M', 'A', 'b1', 'p2', '2014-10-19', 1],
    ['M', 'A', 'b1', 'p2', '2014-10-26', 1],
    ['M', 'B', 'b2', 'p2', '2014-10-19', 3],
    ['M', 'B', 'b2', 'p3', '2014-10-26', 4],
    ['M', 'B', 'b2', 'p3', '2014-11-02', 1]],
    columns = ["animal_type", "disease", "basin", 
    "plant", "week", "infected"])
df['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week'])
```

I want to create output such that every combination of animal_type, disease, basin, and plant has all three weeks represented for joining to another dataframe of additional information for each week.

Desired output:

```
do = pd.DataFrame(
    [['S', 'A', 'b1', 'p1', '2014-10-19', 1],
    ['S', 'A', 'b1', 'p1', '2014-10-26', 3],
    ['S', 'A', 'b1', 'p1', '2014-11-02', 0],
    ['S', 'A', 'b1', 'p2', '2014-10-19', 0],
    ['S', 'A', 'b1', 'p2', '2014-10-26', 4],
    ['S', 'A', 'b1', 'p2', '2014-11-02']0,
    ...
```

This process of creating values for all weeks will be done with other data sets having different diseases, basins, etc., so I need to make this process generalizable.

I tried setting the df index to 'week' and applying a datetime date_range.

```
weeks = pd.date_range('2014-10-13', '2014-11-02', name='week', freq="W")
df.reindex(weeks)
```

When I tried this, I received the error:
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

I tried creating a MultiIndex

```
df.set_index(['animal_type', 'disease', 'basin', "plant", "week"], 
inplace=True)
```

But I don't know how to reindex the week column in the MultiIndex with a date_range.

How can I fill the data set so that every combination of animal_type, disease, basin, and plant has every week represented with a fill value of 0?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different look. At a high level, I perform something tantamount to a cross join by ...

1. separating your df into a "keys" table and a "weeks" table
2. removing duplicates from each
3. joining them with pd.merge on a dummy joining variable
4. and finally merging back on the "infected" field

My code

```
import pandas as pd

### SET UP JOIN ###

#capture unique dates
weeks = df.week.unique()
#make dataframe from weeks
dfWeeks = pd.DataFrame(weeks, columns = ['week'])

#capture "key" columns from df and drop resulting duplicates
dfKeys = df[['animal_type', 'disease', 'basin', 'plant']].drop_duplicates()

#add dummy matching field for cross join
dfWeeks['key'] = 1
dfKeys['key'] = 1

### PERFORM CROSS JOIN ###

dfNew = pd.merge(dfKeys, dfWeeks, on = 'key', how = 'left')
#drop dummy matching field
dfNew.drop('key', axis = 1, inplace = True)

#left merge "infected" back on
dfNew = pd.merge(dfNew, df, on = ['animal_type', 'disease', 'basin', 'plant', 'week'], how = 'left')

#replace NaN w zero
dfNew.infected.fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I guess sometimes you just have to get it out to find the answer. I was able to get the desired output using the following:

```
animal_types = df['animal_type'].unique()
diseases = df['disease'].unique()
basins = df['basin'].unique()
plants = df['plant'].unique()
weeks = pd.date_range('2014-09-21', '2014-11-02', name='week', freq="W")
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([animal_types, diseases, basins, plants, weeks], names = ['animal_type', 'disease', 'basin', "plant", "week"])
df.groupby(['animal_type', 'disease', 'basin', "plant", "week"]).sum().reindex(index=mi).fillna(-9999)
```